# Firebase createUserWithEmailAndPassword() from already authenticated account

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am writing  administative function which allows system admin to create new accounts.Since system admin is already authenticated to system after registering users to firebase with `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` function i get auth error.
How do i handle this kind of situation ?

Comment: show your code, whats the error you get exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regular Firebase JavaScript/Web SDK only allows users to create their own account. There is no way to create an account for another user.

For such tasks you'd typically use the Firebase Admin SDK, which you'd run in a trusted environment (such as on a server you control or in Cloud Functions). [Creating a user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#create_a_user) is a simple API call there.